# How to refresh the items in the comboBox List in JAVA FX

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-8

In my project I am using a comboBox but i need to refresh that comboBox after sometime ...but Unabble to do this...I am doing something like that

```
comboBox.getItems().clear();

for(int i=0; i<Users.length; i++)
    {
        comboBox.getItems().add(Users[i]);          
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

the above code is working properly there was Error somewhere else

```
comboBox.getItems().clear();

for(int i=0; i<Users.length; i++)
{
    comboBox.getItems().add(Users[i]);          
}
```

Comment: Do you think having this here is going to be of any help to any other users?